# How to setup pi-hole on rpi running wireless ap?

Tags: raspbian-buster, access-point, pi-hole, systemd-networkd

I have rpi setup as wireless ap using the below link as instructions.

[Setting up a Raspberry Pi as an access point - the easy way](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/88214/setting-up-a-raspberry-pi-as-an-access-point-the-easy-way/88234#88234)

My exact setup is the one marked as 'recommended' in above link.

I want to install pi-hole to enable network wide ad-blocking. But when I installed and set it up the first time, I couldn't connect any devices to ap as they weren't being assigned an IP address. I tried enabling the "enable DHCP Server" setting in pi-hole but that didn't work either. Any help to properly setup pi-hole appreciated.

Note: I noticed that the setup in the above link requires us to remove 'dhcpcd5' but the pi-hole setup installs it again.

Answer (score 0):

It seems **pi-hole** does not support **systemd-networkd** that is used for the setup you are using. So you are limited to use the default [Raspberry Pi OS](https://www.raspberrypi.org/software/operating-systems/).

Answer (score 0):

A solution could be to run docker on your Raspberry Pi and PiHole (https://hub.docker.com/r/pihole/pihole) as a container and a container as AP(ex. https://pifi.imti.co/).